# Is LZF extension is broken in PHP?

Tags: php, lzf

I have `PHP v7.4.33` with `LZF v1.7.0` extension on `Windows 10 64-bit`:

```
php-7.4.33-ts-vc15-x64
php_lzf-1.7.0-7.4-ts-vc15-x64
```

The function [lzf-decompress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lzf-decompress.php) works for me, and I able to decompress LZF-archive without any problem.

But I can't compress any data using [lzf-compress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lzf-compress.php):

```
echo base64_encode(lzf_compress('abc123'));
```

This function always fails... PHP crashes, and I constantly get the error - "Connection was reset!"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you [posted a bug to PECL](https://github.com/php/pecl-file_formats-lzf/issues/1) in October with no answer, and I'm just linking for anyone else that does discovery

Comment: There would hopefully be some info logged to the error log. You should also be able to trigger this from the command line to get relevant error info.

Comment: @Chris Haas Yes... and no one answers there...

Comment: Works ok for me with 7.4.33 and 1.7.0, compiling fresh via `pecl install lzf` on Ubuntu, so that at least narrows it down to the OS. Can you compile locally? I dunno what sort of effort it takes to get VC up and running these days. I don't suspect you're going to get much support on this module, it's quite old.

Comment: Should I compile with older compiler? How can I get the right compiler version for my php 7.4.33 build? On Windows LZF is DLL-extension. https://www.php.net/manual/en/lzf.installation.php

Comment: [This page](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2) says "Visual C++ 15.0 (Visual Studio 2017)" for PHP 7.4.

Comment: At this point though, I think you might just be better off switching your platform to WSL.  Or your compression to deflate, as you're already past end of life and it's not likely this will continue to work going forward.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to switch to `deflate`. It depends on the current project. If I compile with the latest Visual C++ 15.0 (Visual Studio 2017), will I get PHP MODULE API mismatch error?

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/lzf/1.7.0/windows --- These DLL's do not work with the PHP versions for which they are intended. These are garbage without any SUB-version info.

Comment: Downloaded PHP 7.4 from Apache Lounge with all extensions as suggested in PHP documentation: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6359&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0 ... And LZF compress not working in this build too. So it's broken on Windows.

Comment: Tested PHP 8.2 on Windows. Both LZF compress / decompress not working...